# How to decide server requirements to suit my system?

Tags: php, webserver, windows-server-2012, moodle

How to calculate what kind of server I need for my system. System: moodle Functionality: nothing unusual for moodle Max users online: 100

I know minimal moodle requirements but I don't know how it should scale with users count. Maybe someone could give me advice on how to scaleup requirements based on users?

I'm talking about RAM, CPU, disc space etc.

Comment: You could start with a cloud instance which would be easy to scale and experiment with. Once you know what works for you, you can switch to old school hosting to cut the costs down or decide that you're happy and stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Installing_Moodle#Hardware

Disk space: 200MB for the Moodle code, plus as much as you need to store content. 5GB is probably a realistic minimum.
Processor: 1GHz (min), 2GHz dual core or more recommended.
Memory: 512MB (min), 1GB or more is recommended. 8GB plus is likely on a large production server
Consider separate servers for the web "front ends" and the database. It is much easier to "tune"

That being said make it at least 8GB memory, 4 core, 10 GB for storage. Which is all quite modest. 100 concurrent users I would have the DB on a different server.